# How to include Swagger API's from one spring application into another Spring application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have to create two spring apps App A & App B, where App B will be calling/using API's from app A.
App 'A' will have a swagger API with n number of API's.
App 'B' will have its's own API's, but in the swagger UI it should display the API's of both the app's. 
Could someone tell me how to proceed with this? Sorry for the very vague question(am new to Spring/Java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently just importing the jar file was enough. Also in recourse file, make sure that the API's are not set to @Ignore